# WordPress theme locations gets unchecked automatically

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have a custom menu with more than 100 items in wordpress . 
the issue is that when i select theme location and save it theme location automatically gets unchecked.

it seems to be restricted from Server configurations . i have tweeked `max_input_vars` to 8000 but no luck .

i am still unable to save the menu.

if i remove one item from the menu it works fine.

any one had this issue before or know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

do you have suhosin installed on your server? If that is the case that you should alter

suhosin.post.max_vars
suhosin.request.max_vars

directives in php.ini

Here is a great article on this topic by Uber Menu plugin developer:

http://sevenspark.com/wordpress/menu-item-limit